# Random vector on triangle and trapezoid, conditional and sum

Tags: probability

> Given a random vector $(X,Y)$ with the density $f_{XY}(x,y)=\tfrac{x}{12}$ on the triangle $T_1$ with vertices $(0,0),(0,4),(3,0)$ and density $f_{XY}(x,y)=\tfrac{1}{15}$
>   on the trapezoid $T_2$ with vertices $(6,0),(3,3),(7,3),(7,0)$ I need to find:

1. support and probability function for marginal $X$;
2. support and probability function for $(Y|X=x), 0\le{x}\le7$;
3. support and distribution for $Z=X+Y$.

Based on [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1662113/random-vector-with-density-on-triangle-and-trapezoid):

**Q1**

$f_x(x)=\begin{cases}-\frac{1}{9}x^2+\frac{x}{3},  & \text{if $0\leq x\leq 3$} \\ \frac{x}{15}-\frac{1}{5},  & \text{if $3\leq x\leq 6$} \\ \frac{1}{5},  & \text{if $6\leq x\leq 7$} \end{cases}$

$F_X(x) =
\begin{cases}
\int_{0}^{x} (-\frac{1}{9}v^2+\frac{v}{3})\;dv &= -\dfrac{x^3}{27} + \dfrac{x^2}{6},  & \text{if $0\leq x\leq 3$} \\
\\
F(3) + \int_{3}^{x} (\frac{v}{15}-\frac{1}{5})\;du &= \dfrac{x^2}{30} - \dfrac{x}{5} + \dfrac{8}{10},  & \text{if $3\leq x\leq 6$} \\
\\
F(6) + \int_{6}^{x} (\frac{1}{5})\;du &= \dfrac{x}{5} - \dfrac{2}{5},  & \text{if $6\leq x\leq 7$} \\
\end{cases}$

**Q2**

For $0\leq y\leq 3$

$$\begin{align}
f_{Y|X}(y|x) &= \dfrac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_X(x)} = ?
\end{align}$$

For $3\leq y\leq 4$

$$\begin{align}
f_{Y|X}(y|x) &= \dfrac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_X(x)} = \dfrac{\frac{x}{12}}{-\frac{1}{9}x^2 + \frac{x}{3}}
\end{align}$$

**Q3**

Support of $Z$ is $0\leq Z\leq 4$ and $6\leq Z\leq 10$.

For $0\leq z\leq 3$:

$$P(Z=z) = \int_{x=0}^{z} P(X=x\cap Y=z-x)\;dx = \int_{0}^{z}\dfrac{x}{12}\;dx = \dfrac{z^2}{24}$$

For $3\leq z\leq 4$:

$$P(Z=z) = ?$$

For $6\leq z\leq 7$:

$$P(Z=z) = \int_{x=z-6}^{z} P(X=x\cap Y=z-x)\;dx = \int_{z-6}^{z}\dfrac{1}{15}\;dx = \dfrac{2}{5}$$

For $7\leq z\leq 10$:

$$P(Z=z) = \int_{x=z-7}^{7} P(X=x\cap Y=z-x)\;dx = \int_{z-7}^{7}\dfrac{1}{15}\;dx = -\dfrac{z}{15} + \dfrac{14}{15}$$

All suggestions are welcome :-)

Second edit:

I think $P(Z=z) = -\dfrac{z}{15} + \dfrac{14}{15}$ for $7\leq z\leq 10$ is not correct because 
$$\int_{7}^{10}(-\dfrac{z}{15} + \dfrac{14}{15})dz = \frac{33}{30} \gt 1$$

Comment: $T_1$'s coordinates may need editing

Comment: Thanks, $T_1$'s coordinates are now correct.